# Save frame with current camera angle

Tags: after-effects

I'm an absolute noob to After Effects. I'm not using it for video. I just want to use the 3D ray tracing to get a single image. I've created the 3D image, set the lighting I want and have a camera angle that I like. If I try to save the frame using `Composition -> Save Frame As`, I lose the camera angle - it saves just a front-on view.

How do I save the image as it looks in the composition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following steps work for me for an arbitrary camera.

1. Create the desired composition.
2. Create a camera by going to `Layer -> New -> Camera`. For now just accept the default settings..
3. Position the camera as you desire by changing the `Transform` parameters or by dragging it to the desired position. Here below an image of the `Transform` parameters:
   [image]
4. Make sure that all the layers are 3D layers.
5. In the bar between your composition and the timeline there is a camera dropdown menu:
   [image]
6. Make sure that you choose the camera angle you wish to export. In this case it is `Camera 1`:
   [image]
7. Go to `Composition -> Save Frame As...`

Comment: I have mine set to `Custom View 1`, but it saves the front-on view.

Comment: As I state in the answer at point 6 it is necessary to choose which camera you want. I have added an additional step on how to create a camera as I think you have not added a camera to your scene. `Custom View 1` is not a camera.

Comment: Thank you! At step 3 I right-clicked on the camera layer and selected `Transform -> Center in View`.

Comment: Glad I helped. It's up to you of course to decide which method you're using to place your camera.